# Words are to parse as pictures are to...?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the analogous word to 'parse' in the context of seeing things?

That is, how do you refer to the process of working out what it is you are looking at?

eg. When I opened my eyes, it took me a few seconds to (blank) the scene.

Comment: Appreciate.....?

Comment: The process of "parsing" a picture in your brain is quite complex, but quite unconscious.  But "parsing" words is also quite unconscious if you learn the language as a child and never get into the study of the language structure academically.  If you want to know the process used by the brain to understand pictures you'd have to study up on brain science, just as you study up on syntax/semantics to understand the process of language parsing.

Comment: @HotLicks I consciously parse complex sentences (which come up fairly often in my line of work). I also sometimes consciously have to determine what the arrangement of colours I see actually represents in terms of objects. I don't understand the relevance of your comments to my question.

Comment: @Rathony No, that's a completely different meaning. If I parse a sentence and discover it is insulting me, I don't appreciate it.

Comment: You fail to appreciate all the possible meanings of "appreciate".

Comment: @HotLicks Checking the list at http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appreciate, all the meanings given include a value judgement.

Comment: a few seconds to **interpret** the scene;  a few seconds to **decode** the scene;

Comment: "figure out" ...?

Comment: "Comprehend", " fathom"?

Comment: It is only a rough analogy, since even though a picture has formal elements, it lacks a formal structure comparable to that of language; nor is a picture time-bound in the way utterances are. A picture can have a **gestalt**.  An utterance arrives piece by piece.

Comment: "to *register* the scene?

Comment: Do we register the scene or does the scene register?

Comment: @TimRomano Makes more sense to say *sth registers with sb* than my previous comment. Thanks. [Link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/register). So "it took a few seconds for the scene to *register* (with me)."

Comment: How about [**make out**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/make_1) or [**sink in**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sink_1)?

Answer (score 3):

**[process](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/process)** - to integrate sensory information received so that an action or response is generated.

*When I opened my eyes, it took me a few seconds to **process** the scene.*

Answer (score 2):

> When I opened my eyes, it took me a few seconds to (blank) the scene.

**take in**

Comment: "Take in" may not be the most technically descriptive term but to a native speaker, it says it all! +1

Comment: My first thought too.  Hotly followed by 'figure (out)'.

Answer (score 2):

## parse

You can definitely say "when I woke up it took my mind a few seconds to parse the images before my eyes."

It is completely normal to use this in computer image recognition, image processing.

And that brings us to "process" - "when I woke up it took my mind a few seconds to process the images before my eyes." or "...to process what i was seeing.

Next, there's a **common phrase**...

"It took me awhile to **take that in**!"

"Take that in" means "absorb and understand". It is used specifically when you see some bizarre scene which, well, takes you a while to take in.  It would be rather like saying "to digest that information", particularly about a surprising visual scene or explicit visual puzzle.

Finally "interpret" as suggested in a comment.  "I woke up and it took my mind a few seconds to interpret what my eyes were seeing."

Answer (score 1):

Would **grasp** or **get a hold of** work?

Answer (score 0):

***Understand***, perhaps.  Not a remarkable word, but fits the bill.